# Differences between 'activity', 'newest', and 'added' under the favorites tab?

Tags: support, profile-page, bookmarks, sorting

Do casted votes count as **activity**? Do comments? Does the editing of a question affect its position under **newest**? How is **added** sorted? Some tool-tips wouldn't hurt.

Comment: `Do casted votes count as activity? Do comments?` Assume they do. Then, at least on SO, a lot of questions would be active almost all of the time. How would tooltips improve that situation?

Comment: I meant tool-tips on the sort buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Active** is ordered by the most recently edited or answered question first (editing an answer also counts). Votes or comments do not count as activity.

**Newest** is ordered by the date the question was created and the order won't change if the question is edited.

**Added** is sorted by the date you added it as your favourite. So you if you have two questions, one from 2010 and the other from this year but you added the one from this year first, they will appear in "reverse" order on the added tab, but chronologically on the newest tab.

Comment: True, votes and comments do not affect "last active" timestamp. Worth to add the auto bump by community of questions without upvoted or accepted answers plus placing a bounty also updates the last activity of the question.

Comment: What if an answer is edited?

Comment: @Josh answer posted or edited also bumps the question, changing its last activity timestamp.

Comment: too bad there isn't a way to not-count trivial formatting edits. Why people dredge up two year old posts just to delete a "thank you" beats me.